# Different format for whole numbers and decimal

Tags: c#, string

is there a way of formatting a string to show whole numbers of a decimal number if it follows 00.

example show 10 if number is 10.00.
but show 10.2 if number is 10.2

this is for c#, asp.net

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: Programming language? Platform ? Version? Do you really think this question qualifies on any forum except for PsychicProgrammers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET:

```
if (Math.Floor(d) == d)
    return d.ToString("0");
else
    return d.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is:

```
(if (!= 0 (- (string-to-number x) (floor (string-to-number x))))
    (number-to-string (string-to-number x))
    x)
```